# How to generate 4 square signals using Arduino Mega 2560 below 30hz using timers

Tags: arduino-mega, timers

I would like to generate 4 square signals of different frequencies below 30 hz using timers of Arduino Mega.

I was able to generate 30.6hz signals but I have no idea how to generate lower frequencies.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you can use PWM with timer.  Take a look to this guide: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SecretsOfArduinoPWM

Comment: How low? lower than 1Hz? Is it without pwm, just a 50% square wave? How accurate should be frequency be? Should the signal be very steady or is a software (with or without interrupt) also possible. I assume there is a library that can use all the timers of the arduino mega, but I could not find it yet. Please also tell us what your project is for.

Comment: 30.6 Hz is the slowest you can get from an 8 bit timer. For lower frequencies, you will have to use 16 bit timers.